# Use a single trigger to insert into multiple tables based on a condition

Tags: mysql, datetime, triggers

I have a table named three_current. this tables is inserted with 3 new rows every 1 minutes from another application, so the tables keeps on increasing in rows. These three new rows always have their channel number to be 350, 351, and 352. I want a trigger to insert each of these three rows into three separate tables such that each tables contains data with the same channel number.

The three_current tables is as such:

three_current table

| datetime | channel_number | Value | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/06/2021 22:45:00 | 350 | 100 | 1 |
| 01/06/2021 22:45:00 | 351 | 120 | 1 |
| 01/06/2021 22:45:00 | 352 | 110 | 1 |
| 01/06/2021 22:46:00 | 350 | 95 | 1 |
| 01/06/2021 22:46:00 | 351 | 105 | 1 |
| 01/06/2021 22:46:00 | 352 | 150 | 1 |
| 01/06/2021 22:47:00 | 350 | 195 | 1 |
| 01/06/2021 22:47:00 | 351 | 205 | 1 |
| 01/06/2021 22:47:00 | 352 | 250 | 1 |

I also have three other tables name red_current, yellow_current, and blue_current. I am trying without success to create a trigger to update these three tables based on the channel_number of three_current table such that

red_current table will be

| datetime | channel_number | Value | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/06/2021 22:45:00 | 350 | 100 | 1 |
| 01/06/2021 22:46:00 | 350 | 95 | 1 |
| 01/06/2021 22:47:00 | 350 | 195 | 1 |

yellow_current table will be

| datetime | channel_number | Value | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/06/2021 22:45:00 | 351 | 120 | 1 |
| 01/06/2021 22:46:00 | 351 | 105 | 1 |
| 01/06/2021 22:47:00 | 351 | 205 | 1 |

blue_current table will be

| datetime | channel_number | Value | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/06/2021 22:45:00 | 352 | 110 | 1 |
| 01/06/2021 22:46:00 | 352 | 150 | 1 |
| 01/06/2021 22:47:00 | 352 | 250 | 1 |

But what I get after executing my code is that the red_current, yellow_current and the blue_current tables are all being inserted with rows where the channel number is 350. This means that only the red_current table is correct while the other two tables are duplicates of the red_current table. (I feel my code can only execute for the first row of each updates received by three_current table and thats the row with channel number 350).

My code is as follows:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `add` AFTER INSERT ON `three_current`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
                 DECLARE new_datetime datetime ;           -- choose the datatypes
                 DECLARE new_channel_number int;           -- 
                 DECLARE new_value double;                 --
                 DECLARE new_status smallint;              --
                
                 SET new_datetime = new.datetime ; 
                 SET new_channel_number = new.channel_number ;
                 SET new_value = new.value ;
                 SET new_status = new.status;
                
INSERT INTO red_current (datetime, channel_number, value, status)
    SELECT new.datetime, new.channel_number , new.value, new.status  
    FROM three_current WHERE channel_number = '350'
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE status = new.status;      
    
INSERT INTO yellow_current (datetime, channel_number, value, status)
    SELECT new.datetime, new.channel_number , new.value, new.status  
    FROM three_current WHERE channel_number = '351'
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE status = new.status;  
    
INSERT INTO blue_current (datetime, channel_number, value, status)
    SELECT new.datetime, new.channel_number , new.value, new.status  
    FROM three_current WHERE channel_number = '352'
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE status = new.status  ;  
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server. Please avoid unrelated tags in future.

Comment: You forgot to explain what problem you face with what you have...